# How to organize fair cache in Cassandra Cluster for large number of customers using it?

Tags: caching, cassandra

Is there any recommendation of how to serve large number of customers with Cassandra?

Imagine that all of them read rows (specific per customer) in Cassandra. If we have one big Column Family (CF) we will correspondingly have single memtable per this CF. So, that customers who read data more frequently will displace cache entries of less frequent-in-read customers. And quality of service (i.e. read speed) will differ for different users. This is not fair (all customers must experience the same performance).

Is it normal to allocate separate CF's per customer (e.g. 5000 CF's or more)? As I understand this will cause creation of 5000 memtables what will lead to fair caching because each customer will be served in separate cache (memtable). Am I correct?

And on the other hand, will creation of large number of CF's decrease performance rather than having single big CF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memtables are not caches, they are to ensure writes in Cassandra are sequential on disk.  They are read from when doing queries, but are flushed when they are too big rather than using an eviction policy that is appropriate for a cache.

Having separate column families for each customer will be very inefficient - 1000s of CFs is too many.  Better would be to make sure your customer CF remains in cache.  If you have enough memory then it will (assuming you don't have other CFs on your Cassandra cluster).  Or you could use the row cache and set the size to be big enough to hold all the data in your customer CF.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the memory cost of that many CFs would be horrific. Each CF needs a heap allocation and if I recall that's around the 4MB mark per CF. As you can see, 5000 CFs would not be pretty.

Comment: Thank you Richard for your answer. 

So as I've understood Memtables don't perform caching functions. And in order to increase read speed I should enable row cache. Am I right to say that row cache can be set for each Cassandra node of different size? 
Can the problem of most frequently read user (e.g. Lady Gaga profile) arise with row cache. I mean that reads to Lady Gaga will evict all other entries. 
So, is it possible to organize fair row cache, or I need to shard my cluster (move Lady Gaga to separate cluster)?

Comment: Maybe Cassandra solves this problem easily by adding nodes? I mean that using replication factor e.g. 3 Lady Gaga's entries will be located on 3 nodes and thats why row cache occupied by Gaga will be spread across cluster and it's kind of fair cache solution. "Just add cluster nodes" Am I correct?

Comment: You can set the row cache different sizes on each node, but this is not recommended. Each node should do roughly the same amount of work. If you have your row cache big enough to store all your entries then you won't have problems with eviction.

Comment: Thanks again! But what if nodes will differ in their parameters like memory, disk and etc.? I think the only way is to configure them with different settings on cache.

Comment: It isn't recommended to use inhomogeneous nodes in Cassandra. You could do this with virtual nodes but I'm not aware of anyone who has so there might be surprises.